# Webforms and Script Service Architecture

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a page called Offices.aspx, which displays a few server controls and a Google map related to office locations for my company.

For the server controls, I can bind data in the codebehind like I've always done before the rich-user-experience train came in and put so much in the hands of Javascript.

For my Google map I need to access a script service, so now I've got Offices.svc as well.

Much of the logic that the two need (Offices.aspx and Offices.svc) are the same and I suppose I can separate it into a library but it just seems a little klunky. Wondering if anyone can share some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad architecture. I recommend you to use knockout.js for your client side and MVC as your app type.